# Why does an object keep its inherited property?

Tags: javascript

```
function Dog(name){
    this.name=name;
}
let dogA=new Dog('Paul');
 
Dog.prototype.eat=true;
dogA.eat; //true
```

Now I destroy Dog.prototype, why dogA.eat still there?

```
Dog.prototype=null;
dogA.eat;// Still true?
```

I'm thinking `dogA.eat` inherited from `Dog.prototype`. Now `Dog.prototype` is gone. How can `dogA.eat` still exist?

Comment: `Dog.prototype = null;` doesn’t “destroy” the prototype, it just reassigns the `prototype` property to something else, just like in `let a = {}; const b = a;`, `a = null;` doesn’t affect `b`, doesn’t mutate the object, and doesn’t destroy anything. The original object is still there.

Comment: Still confused since prototype is something else now, why the prototype chain not destoryed?

Comment: See [JavaScript Prototype - Please Clarify](/a/49042583/4642212) and [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](/a/4166723/4642212). See also [How value to \_\_proto\_\_ is assigned in javascript?](/q/45566298/4642212). `Dog.prototype = null;` only affects _newly_ constructed objects. The prototype of existing objects is never touched by this reassignment. The [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-prototype) answers all these questions in more detail.

Comment: ```delete Dog.prototype.eat``` will delete the property. Assigning null will affect new objects.

Comment: Yea I understand the point now. The key concept here is that the original `Dog.prototype` is always there like a normal object. And `dogA.__proto__` is pointing to the object's memory location all the time. Now `Dog.prototype` points to `nul`l in a new memory location (like, initializing again), but dogA.__proto__ is still pointing to the old memory location, so `eat` is still `true`. End of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `eat` is stored in `dogA.__proto__`. When you use `new` operator to create an instance `dogA` of `Dog`, javascript will do `dogA.__proto__ = Dog.prototype = someObject`. Now you make `Dog.prototype = null`, but `dogA.__proto__` still equals to `someObject`. So `dogA.eat` still be `true`. If you make `dogA.__proto__ = null`, then `dogA.eat` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you. Thought eat is stored in Dog.prototype...

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the prototype chain, you need to use `Object.setPrototypeOf(dogA, null)`.

Nulling `Dog.prototype` will only affect new instances created by `new Dog`, not the `Object.getPrototypeOf(dogA)` which still is the object with the `eat` property.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after being stuck for days I realize it basically has nothing to do with prototype. It's all about pointer and memory.

The original memory of `Dog.prototype` stores `eat:true`. Then `Dog.prototype` got re-initialized and pointed to a new memory which stores `null`. On the other hand, `dogA.__proto__` still points to the original memory which contains `eat:true` all the time. Therefore, the re-initializing of `Dog.prototype` won't affect `dogA.__proto__`, cuz they are at different memory locations in the end.